# Unable to send emails in my codeigniter application using mailgun SMTP

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, fsockopen

I have used mailgun smtp to sending emails from my codeignitor app
I am getting following error while sending email

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: `fsockopen()` `[function.fsockopen]`: unable to connect to `smtp.mailgun.org:587` `(Connection timed out)`

PORT `25,465,587` are open/unblocked on server

`allow_url_fopen` is `on` in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Check if your CI app web host/server allows sending email. Sometimes web hosts don't allow sending emails in default to avoid using them as an email spam server. SMTP port might be blocked. I think you can change it I just don't know where. Try contacting your service provider ask them if they allow sending emails using smtp.

:)